# New MVC controller not found when pressing the button

Tags: c#, entity-framework, routes

When i press the employee button on my site it should redirect my to the employee controller i have made. Unfortunately i get the following error code:

Server Error in '/' Application.

HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

I have been trying to get my configuration right without any luck.
any suggestions would be great!

So its a C# MVC with localdb application.
I have tried switching in my connection string:
Data Source=.;

I have tried it without the extra route mapping.

After that i havent found any other solutions yet, therefore im here.

My Routing is:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Employee",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new {controller = "Employee", action ="Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
    }
```

My connection string in web config is:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="HRContext" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=JeroenHRApp1;Integrated Security=SSPI"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

My Controller is:

```
public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
    private HRContext db = new HRContext();

    // GET: Employee
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var employees = db.Employees.Include(e => e.Manager);
        return View(employees.ToList());
    }
```

My HRContext is:

```
namespace JeroenHRApp.DAL
{
  public class HRContext : DbContext
  {

    public HRContext() : base("JeroenHRApp1")
    { 
    }

    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    //public DbSet<Manager> Managers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Team> Teams { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
  } 
}
```

I expact to open up a employee page.

Anyone has any suggestions?

Comment: I think there is no need of the Employee Route Config.Remove this and try

Comment: Tried it, unfortunately without succes. Thanks for the comment non the less :)

Comment: My Homecontroller is as following:

`
namespace JeroenHRApp.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }




        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
    }
}
`

Should i add the Employee controller here?

Comment: the routes look identical. in your code I can only see that you pass the employees to a view named Index.

Comment: do you want to see more of the employee controller?

Comment: Found the problem stupid me...

it was the list item in my layout.cshtml:

                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Employee", "Index", "Employee")</li>


it said contact in the view field.... it used to say Contact...


THanks all for helping me! 

i have learned that i don't need extra route mapping
Action result must always be public.
ctr + F really helps alot with troubleshooting where certain words are.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem stupid me...

it was the list item in my layout.cshtml:

```
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Employee", "Index", "Employee")</li>
```

it said contact in the view field.... it used to say Contact...

THanks all for helping me!

i have learned that i don't need extra route mapping
Action result must always be public.
ctr + F really helps alot with troubleshooting where certain words are.